# Switch Statement not running case as function

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to create a switch statement to filter through all the potential options for a filter on a table but it doesn't recognize the cases when I type anything into the search bar. I can't use an if...else statement for the filter because I need the filters to run together not one instead of the other. I've tried changing the names of the variables to make it more clear that I am designating one var per column but no such luck. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
var Caps = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
var Hyphen = event.target.value.replace(/[-]/g, "");
var rows = document.querySelector("#Catalogue").rows;
var firstCol = rows[i].cells[0].textContent.replace(/[-]/g, '');
var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.replace(/[-]/g, '');
var ColOne =  rows[i].cells[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
var ColThree = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();

function filterTable(event) {

for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) 
{if
(switch(true){

    case (ColThree.indexOf(Caps) > -1 || thirdCol.indexOf(Hyphen) > -1):
        rows[i].style.display = ""
        break;
    case (ColOne.indexOf(Caps) > -1 || firstCol.indexOf(Hyphen) > -1):
        rows[i].style.display = "";
        break;
    case (ColOne.indexOf(Caps) > -1 && firstCol.indexOf(Hyphen) > -1):
        rows[i].style.display = "";
        break;
    case (ColThree.indexOf(Caps) > -1 && thirdCol.indexOf(Hyphen) > -1):
        rows[i].style.display = "";
    })
    else{
        rows[i].style.display = "none"
     }

   }

  }
 document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterTable, 
  false);
```

Comment: Use of switch inside of an if??? WHY? Using` swicth(true)` is also a bad idea. Why are you using that instead of normal if /else if?

Comment: What do you imagine `switch(true) {...}` is supposed to do?

Comment: The if/ else if either runs one filter or the other, not both of them at the same time. I'm trying to get the switch(true) to run the two filters for the case if column One/Three has either hyphens and/or lowercase letters. Is there another command that could do this better? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mistakes here :

- You define variables using your event callback variable as global
  (Caps and al)
- You define variables using your index i outside the
  loop as global (firstCol and al)
- You cannot use a switch statement
  inside an if statement (switch is meant to provide alternatives given
  possible values of a var and let avoid an else if cascade)

An approach could be :

```js
// Edit : rows query can be done only once to save time
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr.items'); // or much precise query if needed

function check(event) {
  let caps = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  let hyphen = caps.replace(/[-]/g, ""); // Edit : caps + hyphen will work
  
  // Browse all rows to check if input matching and hide/show
  // Fortunately row.textContent yields all texts values :)
  for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {  
    let row = rows[i];
    
    // test caps length to allow revert to all hidden when no text to match
    if(caps.length && (row.textContent.indexOf(caps) >= 0 || row.textContent.indexOf(hyphen) >= 0)) {
      row.style.display = null;
      break; // process next row
    }
    
    row.style.display = 'none'; // Hide row (avoid an else)    
  }
}

document.getElementById('my-input').addEventListener('keyup', check, true);
```

```css
table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<p>Type here : <input type="text" id="my-input"></p>
<table>
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Row1</th><th>Row2</th></tr>
<tr class="items" style="display:none"><td>001</td><td>FOO</td><td>BAR</td></tr>
<tr class="items" style="display:none"><td>002</td><td>GOO</td><td>CAR</td></tr>
</table>
```

Rows are hidden by default like in your script I presume. Items values are 001, 002, FOO, BAR, GOO, CAR. Just play with it.

The good news is you can access textContent of the whole row without looking into individual tds, saving many time.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, I can't seem to get the hyphens and lower case to work together, F-o-o doesn't yield any results. Is there anyway to set up the filter so it can apply together on a search option so that                 F-O-O=foo=F-o-o, thanks!

Comment: Simply uppercase hyphen by building it from caps (I've edited like so)